# from HFSM with parallel states to Camunda?

Tags: python, workflow, bpmn, camunda, fsm

I was tasked with implementing an HFSM with parallel states and the ability to transition to multiple parallel states in Python. Unfortunately, I could not find a library that supported this. I was told to look into Camunda. I am having trouble understanding how parallel HFSM relates to Camunda? Is there any way to implement parallel HFSM in Camunda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process engine is a state machine. The process model defines the possible states (events and tasks) and allowed transitions (sequence flows). The token flow represents the state of an instance of this model. There is a concept of sub processes and parallel states/execution/multiple tokens can be achieved by using parallel gateways, inclusive gateways, and non-interrupting events. You also have multi-version enactment at runtime. Camunda would nicely cover the requirement and would do so with the ability to configure the models in a graphical, business-friendly fashion (BPMN2). However, there wouldn't be anything left to implement for you. Maybe some task worker in python. If this is an academic exercise, then the idea is probably not to make an already implemented state machine work, but to roll your own. As you do so, you will find reasons why you would not want to program your own for real-world use cases, how much easier it is to use an existing product, and how much work has gone into various features that are time-consuming to implement yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have to implement one of my company's business processes using HFSM , I looked more into Camunda and its great , but the my boss said he doesn't want to deal with BPMN since he believes its a completely difference thing compared with HFSM.As far as I understood it , BPMN is an evolution of a state machine of some sorts. I wasn't able to find a suitable library to implement HFSM in python so I will have to use Spring State Machine.

Comment: It is not a completely different thing. It just means you wont have your business logic in code or spring configuration files, but instead in a graphical (possibly business-friendly) model, audit information if desired, retries and incident management if required,.... You may also find this interesting: https://blog.bernd-ruecker.com/understanding-the-process-automation-landscape-9406fe019d93

Comment: I agree with you, but we want to keep it lightweight, so I think HFSM is the better approach. Implementing Camunda is a much more serious undertaking and requires much more time to set up, etc. We now have a UML diagram and would have to recreate it using BPMN etc. However, I agree with you that camunda might be a way to go in the long run. Anyway, I have not found a library that supports our needs, so I am still stuck.

Comment: docker run -d --name camunda -p 8080:8080 camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run-latest 
Done ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look at it right away. I also talked to our architect today and he said that for our particular task they prefer hfsm over workflow engines, unfortunately, we did not have much time to discuss his reasons.